# Returning remote API data within Express app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an express app where I just return data from another remote API. Below is the file snippet. I cannot use normal `node-fetch` or `request` as my remote API uses NTLM auth.

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const httpntlm = require('httpntlm');

const url = 'http://myremoteapi.com/products';

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {  
  httpntlm.get(
    {
      url,
      username: 'my_user',
      password: 'my_pass
    },
    (err, resp) => {
      if (err) return err;
      res.send(JSON.parse(resp.body));
    }
  );
});

module.exports = router;
```

Everything works fine.

---

Now, I'd like to take the remote API call outside the `router` method in a function called `getData`.

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const httpntlm = require('httpntlm');

const url = 'http://myremoteapi.com/products';

const getData = httpntlm.get(
    {
      url,
      username: 'my_user',
      password: 'my_pass
    },
    (err, resp) => {
      if (err) return err;
      return JSON.parse(resp.body);
    }
  );

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send(getData) // returns undefined
});

module.exports = router;
```

I am unable to get the same result. Also, I found that the `httpntlm` method does not return a Promise which I can resolve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to solve this is to create the Promise yourself:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const httpntlm = require('httpntlm');

const url = 'http://myremoteapi.com/products';

const getData = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  httpntlm.get({
      url,
      username: 'my_user',
      password: 'my_pass'
    },
    (err, resp) => {
      if (err) reject(err);
      else resolve(JSON.parse(resp.body));
    }
  );
});

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  getData().then(data => res.send(data));
});

module.exports = router;
```

By wrapping `httpntlm.get` like that it becomes thenable, and by making `getData` a function the data is fetched anew whenever you call it.

Comment: A shorter solution is this: https://pastebin.com/exkdiDd6 (which I guess Joe meant to suggest)

Comment: Perfect, this is what I was missing. I did try `.then()` on `getData` but since it was not returning a promise, it did not do anything.