# NodeJS router using another function that calls request does not wait for an answer

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, request

I have some route:

```
router.get('/test', async function (req, res, next) {
    let someValue = await someFunction();
    console.log(someValue);
}
```

And a function which does a `GET` request for some other service:

```
async function someFunction() {
let options = {
    url: `someURL`,
    method: 'GET',
};
request(options, async function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) {
        throw error;
    } else {
        return body['someSpecificValue'];
    }
});
```

}

and yet, it seems that in my router, `someValue` is always printed as `undefined`.

What am I doing wrong? how do I need to wait properly for the answer from `someURL`?

Comment: Your `request` call uses a callback, which means you can't `await` the result. `someFunction()` doesn't return any value. I just posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55597477/returning-remote-api-data-within-express-app/55597644#55597644) as answer to a very similar question; the solution is to turn the callback async function into a thenable one so you can `await` it. See also here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#promises--asyncawait

Comment: @ChrisG Is the only solution for this problem is using Promise? I would prefer using async/await if it possible

Comment: You *have* to use a Promise in order to `await` it. You don't have to write your own Promises though, just use one of the wrappers I linked you to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because someFunction is not returning promise update like below or use [request-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise).

```
function someFunction() {
    let options = {
        url: `someURL`,
        method: 'GET',
    };
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        request(options, function (error, response, body) {
            if (error) {
                return res(error);
            }
            return rej(body['someSpecificValue']);
        });
    });
}
```

**OR**

```
var rp = require('request-promise');

function someFunction() {
    let options = {
        url: `someURL`,
        method: 'GET',
    };
    return rp(options);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) module, which is asynchronous, instead the request

```
npm i node-fetch
```

Here's an example

```js
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1";
const getData = async url => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const json = await response.json();
    console.log(json);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
getData(url);
```